# How to pass data as a tuple into an rdd in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tuples, rdd

I have set of coordinates (x, y) as my data in a csv file. I want to pass these x and y into an RDD[(Double, Double)] as tuples and name it points. I have tried the following but for some reason I get an error saying. "Constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type, found: Array[T], required: String".

```
// Load the data
val data = sc.textFile("data.csv")

// Read the data as an RDD[(Double, Double)]
val points = data.map(line => line.split(",").map{ case Array(x, y) => (x.toDouble, y.toDouble)} )
```

EDIT : Is there any way I can filter these points so that I can handle values that are null (if x or y or both are null in the dataset)? In essence I want to check if the tuple always contains 2 elements. I tried something like this

`val points = data.map(line => line.split(",").filter(!_.isEmpty)).map{ case Array(x, y) => (x.toDouble, y.toDouble)}.filter(_.size > 1)`

but I get an error Type mismatch, expected: (Double, Double) => Boolean, actual: (Double, Double) => Any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code. You have to call second map on output of split i.e list of array

```
// Load the data
      val data = sc.textFile("data.csv")

      // Read the data as an RDD[(Double, Double)]
      val points = data.map(line => line.split(",")).map{ case Array(x, y) => (x.toDouble, y.toDouble)}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can filter these points so that I can handle values that are null (if x or y or both are null in the dataset)? In essence I want to check if the tuple always contains 2 elements. I tried something like this `val points = data.map(line => line.split(",").filter(!_.isEmpty)).map{ case Array(x, y) => (x.toDouble, y.toDouble)}.filter(_.size > 1)` but I get an error Type mismatch, expected: (Double, Double) => Boolean, actual: (Double, Double) => Any

Comment: You have to use filter after splitting like  val points = data.map(line => line.split(",")).filter(arr => arr.length ==2).map{ case Array(x, y) => (x.toDouble, y.toDouble)}

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is almost correct, but you should use :

```
val points = data.map(line => {
  val Array(x, y) = line.split(",")
  (x.toDouble, y.toDouble)
})
```

Or alternatively:

```
val points = data.map(line => {
  line.split(",") match {
    case Array(x, y) => (x.toDouble, y.toDouble)
  }
})
```

The problem of your approach is that you call `map` on `line.split(",")`, i.e. you call map on `Àrray[String]`, so you try to (pattern) match a `String` with `Array(x,y)`

Answer (score 0):

Apache spark has api to read csv file. I prefer to use the api rather that using `textFile` to read csv file as it handles missing values or null internally. Here is the content of my `data.csv` file:

```
12,13
12.3,25.6
12.4
,34.5
```

The desired output can be generated by following way:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DoubleType, StructField, StructType}

val scheam = StructType(Array(
      StructField("x",DoubleType,true),
      StructField("y",DoubleType,true)
    ))
val data_df = spark.read.schema(scheam).csv("data.csv")
data_df.show()
+----+----+
|   x|   y|
+----+----+
|12.0|13.0|
|12.3|25.6|
|12.4|null|
|null|34.5|
//converting the data_df dataframe to RDD[Double,Double]
val points_rdd = data_df.rdd.map{case Row(x:Double,y:Double) => (x,y)}
```

Handling null:

```
val filterd_data_df = data_df.filter(data_df("x").isNotNull && data_df("y").isNotNull).
                rdd.map{case Row(x:Double,y:Double) => (x,y)}
import spark.implicits._
filterd_data_df.toDF("x", "y").show()
+----+----+
|   x|   y|
+----+----+
|12.0|13.0|
|12.3|25.6|
+----+----+
```